# Rust struct using a dyn trait as a field causes an error

Tags: rust

Below is my code:

```rust
trait Animal {}

struct Sheep {}
struct Cow {}

// Implement the `Animal` trait for `Sheep`.
impl Animal for Sheep {}

// Implement the `Animal` trait for `Cow`.
impl Animal for Cow {}

struct Human {
    name: String,
    pet: dyn Animal,
}

impl Human {
    fn new(name: String, animal: dyn Animal) -> Self {
        Human { name, pet: animal }
    }

    fn say_my_name(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.name);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sheep = Sheep {};
    let human = Human::new(String::from("alex"), sheep);

    human.say_my_name();
}
```

and the compiler has some issues with it:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Animal + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:18:26
   |
18 |     fn new(name: String, animal: dyn Animal) -> Self {
   |                          ^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Animal + 'static)`
help: you can use `impl Trait` as the argument type
   |
18 |     fn new(name: String, animal: impl Animal) -> Self {
   |                                  ~~~~
help: function arguments must have a statically known size, borrowed types always have a known size
   |
18 |     fn new(name: String, animal: &dyn Animal) -> Self {
   |                                  +

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:50
   |
29 |     let human = Human::new(String::from("alex"), sheep);
   |                 ----------                       ^^^^^ expected `dyn Animal`, found `Sheep`
   |                 |
   |                 arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected trait object `(dyn Animal + 'static)`
                    found struct `Sheep`
note: associated function defined here
  --> src/main.rs:18:8
   |
18 |     fn new(name: String, animal: dyn Animal) -> Self {
   |        ^^^               ------------------

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Animal + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:29:9
   |
29 |     let human = Human::new(String::from("alex"), sheep);
   |         ^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: within `Human`, the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Animal + 'static)`
note: required because it appears within the type `Human`
  --> src/main.rs:12:8
   |
12 | struct Human {
   |        ^^^^^
   = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
   = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Animal + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:29:50
   |
29 |     let human = Human::new(String::from("alex"), sheep);
   |                                                  ^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Animal + 'static)`
   = note: all function arguments must have a statically known size
```

The compiler reports an error in my code because it says the size of `dyn Animal` cannot be known at compilation time. However, the name field of `Human` is also of dynamic size as it's typeof `String`, which means we can't know the size of name at compilation time. So, how can this work?

I know I can fixed it with a `Box` like this:

```
trait Animal {}

struct Sheep {}
struct Cow {}

// Implement the `Animal` trait for `Sheep`.
impl Animal for Sheep {}

// Implement the `Animal` trait for `Cow`.
impl Animal for Cow {}

struct Human {
    name: String,
    pet: Box<dyn Animal>,
}

impl Human {
    fn new(name: String, animal: Box<dyn Animal>) -> Self {
        Human { name, pet: animal }
    }

    fn say_my_name(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.name);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sheep = Box::new(Sheep {});
    let human = Human::new(String::from("alex"), sheep);

    human.say_my_name();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When we say "the size of" a type, we don't actually count how many total bytes it takes up. We're simply counting the amount of space it *immediately* needs on the stack. And a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#365) is (currently) defines as `Vec<u8>`, where [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#396) is basically a pointer and a size. Regardless of how many elements are actually *in* the vector (equivalently, the string), the "size" on the stack is the same: enough space to store a pointer and a size.

`dyn Animal` is different. `dyn Animal` has a varying size depending on who's implementing the `Animal` trait. That's why we need an explicit layer of indirection such as `Box` (for owned trait objects) or `&` (for borrowed). Your analogy holds better for `str`, which is actually an unsized type (try writing a function that takes an `str` as a parameter; you'll get the same error message). That's because `str` is actually the underlying string buffer and requires an explicit layer of indirection (usually `&str`) to become sized. On the other hand, `String` already has that indirection built-in.